# magento exceptions issue

Tags: error, exception

i have an issue in `magento 1.7` but I cannot see which directory this error is referring too, its probably staring me in the face but as im not a developer I cannot see where it is coming from

```
2015-05-12T12:56:50+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Directory is not writable' in /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Soczed/Less/Model/Observer.php(193): Mage::throwException('Directory is no...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Soczed_Less_Model_Observer->beforeLayoutRender(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Soczed_Less_Model_Observer), 'beforeLayoutRen...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(384): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(147): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(3698, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

also I must have an error somewhere but as my developer abandoned his work I need to find which file is referring to a directory as below as we don't have a directory called newsite as in the below, I cant see whats referring to this as it should just be `httpdocs/skin` and not `httpdocs/newsite/skin`

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'load error: failed to find /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/newsite/skin/frontend/mtorion/default/css/styles.less' in /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Soczed/less/lessc.inc.php:2379
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Soczed/less/lessc.inc.php(2528): lessc->__construct('/var/www/vhosts...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Soczed/Less/Model/Observer.php(179): lessc::cexecute(Array, false, Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Soczed_Less_Model_Observer->beforeLayoutRender(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Soczed_Less_Model_Observer), 'beforeLayoutRen...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(384): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php(69): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController->indexAction()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mfeuk.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer

Comment: app/code/community/Soczed/Less/Model/Observer.php check this

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with the LESS CSS plugin by soczed, most likely an incorrect path in it.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `app/code/community/Soczed/Less/Model/Observer.php` then go to line 193 and edit the following

```
Mage::throwException($result.': '.$cssFile);
```

Refresh the page and now the error message should show the path to the file it's trying to write. Then you can just make sure the permissions on this directory are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with this extension before. What you have listed are two separate issues relating to the same module.

1. Firstly, in order to solve the writable dir issue there should be a folder in skin/frontend/mtorion/default/css called _config. Ensure that this folder is writable by the server as well as all the files in it.
2. Secondly the error that you are getting is cause the file location that is being used has been cached during development. In the admin there is a menu or submenu, I can not say for sure as I have seen some theme developers override this location to make it look like theirs, there is a link to "Less Files" or "Manage Less Files". If you can find this you need reset the cache for each record, there is a mass action on the listing page for this. If you can not find this record and comfortable with editing tables in mysql, you need to edit the table "sl_less_file" and set the data in the cache column to null.

Comment: i cannot see this in admin but in the table looks like this, which one to I need to change if any, sorry it wont paste, there are two settings, use_global_variables are all set to 1 and force_global_variables are all set to 0

Comment: cache example 
a:3:{s:4:"root";s:76:"C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\mfe... 
 do I need to just delete these and change to null

Comment: First I would leave the additional fields as is. The developer that you had would of made changes to suite what he had developed. So to start just set the cache to null, flush magento cache and reload the page. Hopefully this is all that you need to get the site working correctly as the developer intended

Comment: yes that worked and it no longer tries to go to that file, thank you